# LINQ only returns one item in collection

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I have a `Project` model that has a collection of `AppUsers` assigned to be `ProjectManagers` or the more general case of `Users`

```
public class Project
    {
        public int ProjectID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " Please enter a project name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AppUser> ProjectManagers { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AppUser> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

In my controller, I try to generate a list of all the project a particular `AppUser` is assigned to, regardless if they are in the `ProjectManagers` or `Users` collection

```
projectList = repository.Projects.Where(p => p.ProjectManagers.Contains(user) || p.Users.Contains(user));
```

However, if an `AppUser` is involved with more than one `Project` only the last `Project` populates this list. How do I ensure all associated projects are returned?

My `AppUser` model:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        //literally does nothing at this point and 
        // is merely a placeholder until I add more
    }
```

In my controller I use the `List` action method to display all the `Projects` related to the `AppUser`. This is the part that isn't working correctly, it's only returning a single `Project`

```
public async Task<IActionResult> List(int page = 1)
        {
            var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);
            if(user != null)
            {
                IQueryable<Project> projectList = GetUserProjects(page, user);
                var model = GetProjectsListViewModel(projectList, page, user);
                return View(model);
            }
            TempData["message"] = "User not found";
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

The following methods are used to generate the lists and the models for pagination

```
 public ProjectsListViewModel GetProjectsListViewModel (IQueryable<Project> projectList, int page, AppUser user)
        {
            ProjectsListViewModel model = new ProjectsListViewModel();
            model.Projects = projectList
                    .OrderBy(p => p.ProjectID)
                    .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
                    .Take(PageSize);
            model.PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                TotalItems = projectList.Count()
            };
            return model;
        }

        public IQueryable<Project> GetUserProjects(int page, AppUser user)
        {
            IQueryable<Project> projectList;
            //IQueryable<Project> result;
            if (user.UserName == "Admin")
            {
                projectList = repository.Projects;
            }
            else
            {

               projectList = repository.Projects
                .Where(p => p.ProjectManagers.Any(pm => pm.Id == user.Id) || p.Users.Any(u => u.Id == user.Id))
                .Select(x => new { UserId = user.Id, Projects = x })
                .GroupBy(p => p.UserId)
                .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(p => p.Projects.ProjectID).First().Projects);

                //None of the commented out code works either
                //projectList = repository.Projects.Where(p => p.ProjectManagers.Contains(user) || p.Users.Contains(user) || p.CommissioningAuthorities.Contains(user));

                //foreach (Project p in repository.Projects)
                //{
                //    if(p.ProjectManagers.Contains(user) || p.Users.Contains(user) || p.CommissioningAuthorities.Contains(user))
                //    {
                //        projectList.ToList().Add(p);
                //    }

                //}
            }
            return projectList;
        }
```

***EDIT***
I noticed when I run `proj.ProjectManagers.Add(appUser);`, it will add that user as a `ProjectManager` but it looks like it it also deletes them from the `ProjectManager` collection of any other project they were previously assigned

Comment: Does `AppUser` override `GetHashCode` and `Equals`?  If not do you have the exact same reference in both projects?  Because if you don't override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` then it will do reference equality and only match on the exact same object and not on one with an equivalent value.

Comment: @juharr what would they need to be overridden to do? This is something I haven't implemented on this and am not quite sure how to begin. Right now `AppUser` extends `IdentityUser` but I have not added any additional properties

Comment: It depends on what you have in `AppUser`.  Lets say you want to match on a `Name` property then you'd make the `Equals` compare the names and `GetHashCode` would just return the `Name.GetHashCode`.

Comment: Actually if this is EF then you'd just need to change the code to match on whatever the PK is like Ashkan has in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I wasn't using a many-to-many joint table. So when I added an `AppUser` to a `Project`, it deleted the relationship between any previous objects. Thus, only one `Project` would be associated with a user. To fix this, I created the class:

```
public class ProjectManager
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }

    public string AppUserID { get; set; }
    public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
}
```

and added this collection to my `AppUser` class:

```
    public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ICollection<ProjectManager> ProjectsAsManager { get; set; }
    }
```

And added the following to my dbContext:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectManager>()
                .HasKey(ppm => new { ppm.ProjectID, ppm.AppUserID });

            modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectManager>()
                .HasOne(pm => pm.AppUser)
                .WithMany(p => p.ProjectsAsManager)
                .HasForeignKey(pm => pm.AppUserID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectManager>()
                .HasOne(pm => pm.Project)
                .WithMany(p => p.ProjectManagers)
                .HasForeignKey(pm => pm.ProjectID);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
```

After running a migration and update, a single user can now be associated with more than one `Project` as a `ProjectManager`

Answer (score 0):

In here as there is no datetime in your project class, I assume that the project with bigger Id is the newer one:

```
var result = Projects
    .Where(p => p.ProjectManagers.Any(pm => pm.Id == user.Id)
           || p.Users.Any(u => u.Id == user.Id))
    .Select(x => new { UserId = user.Id, Projects = x })
    .GroupBy(p => p.UserId)
    .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(p => p.Projects.ProjectID).First().Project);
```

To get all projects of the user:

```
var result = Projects
    .Where(p => p.ProjectManagers.Any(pm => pm.Id == user.Id)
           || p.Users.Any(u => u.Id == user.Id));
```

Comment: I think this is most likely the answer but I'm getting an error on `ProjectID` of `x.OrderByDescending(p => p.ProjectID).First())` stating "<anonymous type string: UserId, Project Project> does not contain a definition for 'ProjectID'"

Comment: @coolhand yes there was an error in my code. please see my edited answer.

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding. I'm trying to return an `IQueryable<Project> projectList;` but your `result` is `{string UserId, Project Projects}`

Comment: Oh yeah, just add .Project after first. I just added it to the answer. ;) this happens when you answer at 7 am, and you haven't slept

Comment: I'm tracking what you're doing now (except the answer needs `respository.Projects` and `First().Projects` to pass), but I'm still getting the same result of a single project being returned

Comment: it should return single project per user

Comment: Oh, then that's the miscommunication. I want to return all `Projects` associated with that user. I'll add additional controller logic to hopefully clarify what I'm trying to do

Comment: ohhhh reallyyyyyyy, that was very simple. check my answer.

Comment: I'm still getting the same behavior

Comment: with this `var result = Projects
    .Where(p => p.ProjectManagers.Any(pm => pm.Id == user.Id)
           || p.Users.Any(u => u.Id == user.Id));`?

Comment: Yessir, all I get returned is the last entered `Project`. I'm beginning to wonder if it's an issue with the way I have my repository set up

Comment: you should get all the projects, unless the user is only associated with one project.

Comment: As I test it, I show a project associated with a user (e.g., Test1). If I create a Test2 `Project` all I see for that user is the Test2 project. If I debug with Admin rights, I can see that Test1 still has the user as a `ProjectManager`

Comment: I noticed when I run `proj.ProjectManagers.Add(appUser);` it adds that user to a particular project, but deletes them from any previous projects. Is there a more appropriate way to add a user?