# .NET Core EF Primary Key Error on context.SaveChanges()

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

My `Project` model has a collection of `<AppUsers>`:

```
public class Project
    {
        public int ProjectID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " Please enter a project name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " Please enter a project description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AppUser> ProjectManagers { get; set; }
}

public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
       //just a placeholder for now until I add properties later
    }
```

In my EF repository, I get an error when I try to assign any user to more than one project as a part of the `ProjectManager` collection (e.g., I can assign them to Project1 but when I assign them to Project2 it throws an exception).

```
public void AddProjectManager(int projectID, AppUser user)
        {
            Project proj = context.Projects.Include(p => p.ProjectManagers).FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProjectID == projectID);
            if (!proj.ProjectManagers.Any(pm => pm.Id == user.Id))
            {
                AppUser appUser = identityContext.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == user.Id);
                if (appUser != null)
                {
                    proj.ProjectManagers.Add(appUser);
                    //ERROR OCCURS HERE WHEN I TRY TO SAVE
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
```

I get the following error:

`Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_AppUser'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AppUser'. The duplicate key value is (xxx).`

I've tried using a `UserManager` approach, but get the same error

Comment: Can one AppUser be assigned to multiple Projects?

Comment: @Priyank Panchal that was my intent, to allow one user to be assigned to multiple projects. I may be implementing that idea incorrectly though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally this would result in a multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker (see: [Why is my entity being referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55129126/why-is-my-entity-being-referenced-by-multiple-instances-of-ientitychangetracker/55309308#55309308)) however I suspect your identityContext has lazy loading proxies turned off, so you'll get the PK exception.

The issue will be that you are loading the user from one context, (identityContext) and trying to save a reference to it via another context. (context)  You want to load the reference from the same context. The application context knows about AppUser, but it didn't load the instance you are associating to the project because that was loaded from a different context so it is treating it as a new AppUser.

The solution is to load the AppUser from `context` rather than `identityContext`

```
public void AddProjectManager(int projectID, AppUser user)
{
    Project proj = context.Projects.Include(p => p.ProjectManagers).FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProjectID == projectID);
    if (!proj.ProjectManagers.Any(pm => pm.Id == user.Id))
    {
         AppUser appUser = context.AspNetUsers.Single(p => p.Id == user.Id);
         proj.ProjectManagers.Add(appUser);
         context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

If you don't have a DbSet for the AspNetUser in the application context, you would need to add it. Normally for something like this, I wouldn't add the entire AspNetUser entity to the application context, but rather a lightweight entity with just the details I need (ID and Name for instance) and then my application entities would reference this lightweight instance (pointed at the same table) to speed up data operations for this association.

Comment: I used `public IQueryable<AppUser> AppUsers => context.AppUsers;` in combination with `AppUser appUser = context.AppUsers.Single(u => u.Id == user.Id);` in my repository to use the same context as you suggested, but the `AppUsers` table in the database does not get populated with anything, resulting in a `sequence has no members` error. Do I need to merge my `AppIdentityDbContext.cs` and `ApplicationDbContext.cs` classes for this to work?

Comment: What table does the AppIdentityDbContext map to for the App Users then? Is it a different database?  If it's a separate database you may want to set up replication to ensure your application database has the users. Otherwise you could handle where a user isn't found in the app database and create a new user, though this will not be in-sync with the source of truth you use for authentication.

Comment: at the moment, they are the same database so it doesn't much matter. I originally used different `DbContext` classes in case I wanted to point to another database set of `AppUsers`.What you eluded to works, however, I seem to bounce back and forth between two issues: when I keep them in the same context, I get an issue where only one project is returned from the repository; if I put them in different contexts, this seems to resolve but then I get the `PK` issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55291755/linq-only-returns-one-item-in-collection)

Comment: Did `identityContext.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == user.Id);` return a user?  (Seems odd if you were authenticating if the table didn't contain a user record.)  On a hunch it sounds like the two contexts are pointing at different databases.

Comment: Yes, `AspNetUsers` returned a user from the default `Identity` tables. If I tried to get an `AppUser` table into the other database, that's when it wouldn't return anything (the cross-database issue you clarified)